# Replace html elements from a list of elements

Tags: javascript, html

This may sound a dumb question. I have a set of images inside a page. And these images doesnt have an ID but a class. I want to get these elements by their class names and replace each of them with different content. How should I do that.

Comment: `$('img.CLASS_NAME').replaceWith(newContent )`

Comment: @Mani — _"replace each of them with different content"_

Comment: Do you have a specific order in which the new content should be or you dont care and you just want have a different content? and do the images have the same class or are they different?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a short sample of how the HTML would look before and after the replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following using vanilla JavaScript (no jQuery) and does:

- Select images in your page which have a class assigned (in this example `imageClass`). The `document.querySelectorAll()` allows you to select DOM elements using CSS3 selectors.
- Change "content" for each image (src link), so yo ucan show up different images.

Click the button in the example to change "content" for images.

```js
(function() {
  var changeContent = function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.imageClass').forEach(function(image) {
      image.src = 'https://placeimg.com/340/280/people'
    });

  };
  document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', changeContent);
})();
```

```html
<button id="btn" type="button">Change Images</button>
<img class="imageClass" src="https://placeimg.com/240/180/animals">
<img class="imageClass" src="https://placeimg.com/240/180/animals">
<img class="imageClass" src="https://placeimg.com/240/180/animals">
<img class="imageClass" src="https://placeimg.com/240/180/animals">
```